# refence a user and limit table view accordingly xcrud application

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I am trying to understand Xcrud - https://codecanyon.net/item/xcrud-data-management-system-php-crud/3215400

I have 2 tables - both nearly identical in structure  with hundreds of thousands of rows on one of of them (the punlic table).
 the first table is the “public” table, where all logged in users users have access to it and it has an extra row called assigend user which is basically supposed to restrict the ability to edit that row/record to which a user is assigned but the assigned user - it should still remain public on the public table just not editable to other users unless that user removes himslef from that record.

The second table is a user specific table which contains only records either added by current user or edited records by that user from the public table . 
to simplify things - the first table is genrated using the xcrud syntax :

```
echo Xcrud::get_instance()->table('public_table');
```

and is placed on a php page called public.php

and the second one is same just refrenced in another table -

```
echo Xcrud::get_instance()->table('private_table');
```

which is place on another page called private.php

so far each table is using a single php file - and is supposed to be either public or private - private meaning only assigned records are visible by user id .
the problems ive faced are - when i tried to use joint table rows between the 2 tables - assigned_user and user_id in both to limit the views according to the user and specify the assigned user  it simply doesnt work on the private table.
i suppose i should refrence the current logged in user in the top of the php files so i can limit the views according to current user but i cannot find the variable i should use to do that, without breaking the entire page output.
perhaps im trying this all wrong and should just use a pribilage based system like xavier does and build a third table - roles and use that to specify what table is currently shown.

i suppose there is an easier way to do it - but im just unable to get there - when ever a user currently  edits any record in the public table it is supposed to grant edit permissions to only that user, but instead it still shows it only in public table and doesnt show it in the user table, and is still editable to all other users - also in mysql it doesnt add that record to the user table with the assigned user id.
a similar solution i saw is to somehow allow users to import all records they want to, using a select statemnt to their user specific table and then refrence the records by user id on the user specific table but again have no idea how to edit the source code to allow import by select statemnt while allowing that record to remain in both tables. 
 any help would be appricaited...

i thought id maybe create the mysql tables as such -

```
    CREATE TABLE `records` (
      `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `record_item1` varchar(144) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `user_role` ENUM('admin', 'not_registered', registered_user ) NOT NULL DEFAULT `not_registered`,
      `assigned_user_id` bigint(400) unsigned NOT NULL,

      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      KEY `assigned_user_id` (`user_ID`)
    );                                                

            CREATE TABLE `users` (
          `user_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          `user_pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          `user_role` ENUM('admin', 'not_registered', registered_user) NOT NULL DEFAULT `not_registered`,
          `user_registration` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
          KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)   
);
```

And after that try to use php to show records by id but im missing something - this is what i tried

```
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['Username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['Email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['Assigned_Records']; ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php if($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin', 'registered_user' ): ?>
            <button class="w3-btn w3-green"><a href="clone.php?id=<?php echo $res['user_ID']; ?>">Clone / Import Record</a></button>
            <button class="w3-btn w3-red"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $res['user_ID']; ?>">Update Record</a></button>
        <?php elseif($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'not_registered'): ?>
            ...
        <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

My problem begins at how to write the clone.php to allow import to another table for specific record along with the user id who imported it, and the same for update.php - without removing the record from the public table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass userid to other page,then you need to write select query based on your userid.. then write insert query to other page.

Comment: can use share a more detailed example? currently im using 2 pages - a public.php and private.php - i tried to add the select query on the public page as a bottom near the end of each row of each record but it gets too complicated to write a query that copies that row into the private_user table, i alsoo thoutgh perhaps to try and use a single table and the just add a column with the assigend uer but that screws everything up - since after a user is assigned to a record that record cant be reasssigned - so how would i go about allowin users to clone records? i think i  built the db incorectly?

Comment: from the xcrud developer - the user sessions are declared as such -     
             $xcrud->where('user_id',$_SESSION[‘user_id’]);   so if i understood your answer - create a thrid page wehre i show records with the above xcud statement to seprate between user data? how would that prevent users from overwriting a record if both of them are updating it? thats basically my main issue - so either i need to somehow allow cloning of a record or use several tables?